# How to update a DATE variable automatically?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I created a table for storing the version of a software (it's an example) with an id column, start date and end date. The start date is known when the record is inserted but not the end date, which depends on the date of creation of the new version.

My idea is to enter the variable as NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
start_date DATE NOT NULL,
end_date DATE,
);
```

Once the new version is created, the NULL value is changed to the real date. Is there any way to do this automatically when a new record is inserted to the table?

**EDIT:** I tried this in DB Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE kit (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(45), start 
DATE, end DATE); 

INSERT INTO kit (name, start) 
VALUES("V1.0", "2018-09-18");

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_version AFTER INSERT ON kit 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    SET OLD.end = CURDATE();
END // 

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO kit (name, start) VALUES("V2.0", "2019-04-16");
```

After that, I got this error:

```
Schema Error: Error: ER_TRG_CANT_CHANGE_ROW: Updating of OLD row is not 
allowed in trigger
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You have to send another query for updating old row, you can make it by trigger if you don't want it application layer.

Comment: You can set it to Current timestamp so whenever new record will be inserted it will hold current date and later you can change with desired input.

Comment: either a currunt timestamp or create a trigger.

Comment: You want to update the older version when new version is created? If so then triggers is (perhaps the only) option.

Comment: I read that it's not possible to update an old row using a trigger. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the post!